# Proving the affine hull definition from the intersection of affine spaces (Rockafellar's Convex Analysis)

Tags: algebraic-topology, convex-analysis, simplex, convex-hulls

While self-studying Rockafellar's Convex Analysis, I am struggling with the proof on Rockafellar's note on page 6 about proving the definition of the affine hull. Note that I *don't* want the intuitive definition of the affine hull as most of the existing answers did. Rather I want a rigorous proof of the following section.

> Therefore given any $S \subset R^n$ there exists a unique smallest affine set containing S (namely the intersection of the collection of affine sets $M$ such that $M\supset S$). This set is called affine hull of S and is denoted by aff S. It can be proved as an exercise, that aff S consists of the vectors of the form $\lambda_1 x_1 + \ldots+\lambda_m x_m$, such that $x_i \in S$ and $\lambda_1 + \ldots + \lambda_m = 1$.

Now I see the proof other way around, that is given S an affine space any *convex* combination of the points will lie in S. Also intuitively we understand that the points inside the hull has to be *comvex* combination in order to fall inside S, otherwise it will go outside. But I can't prove it. Please help.

Comment: I have often found Stephen Boyd's convex optimization to be a better self study book rather than rockafella.. Maybe you can try that it

Comment: I agree but, I find Rochafellar really concise. I fear I would not be able to cover Boyd in my lifetime.

Comment: @rostader That book has two authors.

Comment: @HirakSarkar I've answered your question I believe, in great detail.  I also struggled with this topic when reading Vick's *Homology Theory*.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ be any set and define its **convex hull** to be the intersection of all convex sets containing $S$, where a **convex set** $C$ is defined to be a set such that the segment between any two points lies entirely in $C$.

Let $X = \{ \sum_{i=1}^n t_i x_i: \sum_i t_i = 1, x_i \in S\}$ be the set of convex combinations of points in $S$.

The proof that $S \subset X$ is straight-forward, however, I will go through it (since the version I needed about convex hulls of a $p$-simplex is slightly different).

It is enough to show that $X$ is a convex set since then by definition of $S$ being the intersection of all convex sets, we have automatically $S \subset X$.

Consider the segment as $0 \leq t \leq 1$: $s(t) = (1-t)x + ty$ where $z= \sum_{x\in S} t_x x \in X$ and $y = \sum_{x \in S} s_x x \in X$ and where $\sum_{x\in S} s_x = 1$ and $\sum_{x \in S} t_x = 1$ are both convergent sums.  If you need to, impose that $t_x, s_x = 0$ for all but a finite number or $x \in S$.

Then we have:

$$
s(t) = (1-t)\sum_x t_x z + t\sum_x s_x x = \\
\sum_x \left((1-t) t_x + t s_x \right) x
$$

Then $r_x = (1-t)t_x + ts_x$ is such that $\sum_x r_x = 1$ since: $\sum_x r_x = \sum_x t_x - t \sum_x t_x + t\sum_x s_x$.  Then two sums on the right cancel each other, and you're left with $\sum_x t_x = 1$.  If in addition we needed positive $t_x, s_x \geq 0$, then $r_x \geq 0$ as well in that case (some problems specify non-negativity of the coefficients).

Thus we've proven that $X$ is convex or that $S \subset X$.

But not only that, we proved that the set of all *"convergent" convex combinations* is convex (i.e. not just usual, finite convex combinations).

---

Now, to prove the converse to me seems a little more tricky.  We want to show that $S$ is closed under taking convex combinations of points of $S$ since then, by definition of $X$ we would have $X \subset S$.

Let $y = \sum_{x \in S} t_x x$ be a convex combination of the points of $S$, i.e. $\sum_{x \in S} t_x = 1$ (and if the problem requires, also specify that $t_x \geq 0, \forall x$).

Then $y = \sum_{x \in S} t_x x = t_{x'}x' + \sum_{x \in S \\ x \neq x'} t_x x$, where $x'$ is chosen so that $t_{x'} \neq 0$, which must exist since $\sum_{x \in S} t_x = 1$.

Now write $y = t_{x'} x' + (1 - t_{x'})\sum_{x \in S \\ x \neq x'} \dfrac{t_x}{1-t_{x'}} x \tag{1}$.

Clearly, $\sum_{x \in S \\ x \neq x'} \dfrac{t_x}{1 - t_{x'}} = 1$.  Now, unless there is some way to do induction "on an arbitrary subset" of $\Bbb{R}^n$, we must now use the fact that our convex combinations are finite sums ($t_x = 0$ for all but a finite number of $x \in S$)  Clearly then, by induction we have that the sum on the write is a strictly smaller convex combination and of course the base case is true.  On the other hand $y$ split up that way as in (1) is itself a convex combination of two points of $S$.  And we're done.  $\square$

The above is clearly general enough to handle the case of $p$-simplices as well, which is what I was after when reading Vick's *Homology Theory - an Introduction to Algebraic Topology*.  That is the remark right above Proposition 1.2 on page 2.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you have a space $X(S)$ associated to a set $S$, that is the smallest set satisfying a certain property $P$ (in this case, being affine), to prove that another set $Y$ is $X(S)=Y$, what you do is 1) Prove that $Y$ is contained in every set with property $P$ (which is what you did, every convex combination of points of $S$ lies in every affine space containing $S$) and 2) Prove that $Y$ has the property $P$ (in this case, prove that all convex combinations of points in $S$ form an affine set), then $$Y\subseteq X(S)$$ by point 1) and $$X(S)\subseteq Y$$ being $X(S)$ the $\textit{smallest}$ set satisfying $P$, so you reach the conclusion $$X(S)=Y$$So, can you prove that all convex combinations of points in $S$ form an affine set? in which case you're done

**Edit** Addressing the comment: I don't know if there is a way to directly prove that every element of $\text{aff}(S)=X(S)$ is a convex combination of elements from $S$ from the definition of $X(S)$. The definition of $X(S)$ only tells you that it is the intersection of all affine spaces containing $S$. In particular, it doesn't tell you what's the form of a generic element of $X(S)$, so to prove that every element $v\in X(S)$ is a convex combination of elements in $S$, the only way I see would be to prove that a point $v$ that is not a convex combination of elements from $S$ doesn't belong to $X(S)$ by showing that there is an affine set $A$ containing $S$ and not containing $v$. The best choice for this affine set $A$ is the set $CC(S)$ of all convex combinations of elements in $S$ and if you prove that $CC(S)$ is an affine set, then by definition $$X(S)\subseteq CC(S)$$ which proves that every element in $X(S)$ is indeed a convex combination of elements from $S$. So in the end, it all comes down to prove that $CC(S)$ is an affine space, thus it contains $X(S)$.

Comment: Thanks, actually I indeed could do the proof in that way, but I was wondering if there is a way to prove $\sum_i \lambda_i = 1$ when we consider the smallest intersection of the affine spaces.